# Enable Image zoom functionality in Angular 8 application

Tags: bootstrap-4, angular-material, zooming, angular8

I am trying to add image zoom functionality in Angular 8 application.

Checked [ng-img-magnifier](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-img-magnifier/v/1.2.1) and [ngx-image-zoom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-image-zoom) which are not supported with Angular 8.

Found this link to implement zoom which works.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-6z9sob?file=package.json,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

I am using angular-material and bootstrap. Is there any other library supported with Angular 8 application for zoom in/zoom out of image.